# Updating the url list apt-get uses in debian

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

When I do 'apt-get update' on my VPS I get a lot of error messages:

```
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/volatile/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/volatile/contrib Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/volatile/non-free Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/updates/contrib Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org lenny/updates/non-free Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-volatile/dists/lenny/volatile/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-volatile/dists/lenny/volatile/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-volatile/dists/lenny/volatile/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security/dists/lenny/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security/dists/lenny/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security/dists/lenny/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help me update this list to make all the urls work.

Sorry for the strange title of the question but I do not know the right terms.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as of 2012.04: http://serverfault.com/questions/373314/debian-5-0-lenny-apt-sources-fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Chances are your host is using one of the older OpenVZ templates which had bad repo URLs.

Try my list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free 
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main
```

Comment: You're most welcome!

Comment: This answer id *obsolete*: see http://serverfault.com/questions/373314/debian-5-0-lenny-apt-sources-fail

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem `http://ftp.devian.org/debian-security` exists. When viewing `http://ftp.debian.org/`, all i see is `debian/`

Maybe try `security.debian.org`?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what one may think given its name, `ftp.debian.org` is not a more complete mirror than other Debian mirrors. For example, it doesn't have `debian-volatile`. The Debian web site has a [list of debian-volatile mirrors](http://www.debian.org/volatile/volatile-mirrors). Security updates should come directly from `security.debian.org`.

You need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Change the volatile and security lines to something like

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

While you're at it, you might as well change the core line to use `ftp.nl.debian.org` as well.